# How to start JPA in a Guice + Quartz web application?

Tags: java, jpa, quartz-scheduler, guice

I'm having some kind of trouble with an application, I use Guice for injections with some background tasks handled by Quartz.

As stated by the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JPA), I'm using a PersistFilter to handle my transactions and starting my JPAService. The problem is that the first time my jobs are executed, the JPAService is not started yet and my `unitOfWork.begin()` throws an exception :

```
2013-07-01 11:45:05,527 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR com.foo.core.synchronization.impl.Result.notifyListener(Result.java:65) - Error while notifying synchronization listener
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.begin(JpaPersistService.java:70)
        at com.foo.convert.DiscoveryService.parsedElement(DiscoveryService.java:148)
        at com.foo.convert.DiscoveryService.parsedElement(DiscoveryService.java:67)
        at com.foo.core.synchronization.impl.Result.notifyListener(Result.java:62)
        at com.foo.core.synchronization.impl.Synchronizer.synchronize(Synchronizer.java:68)
        at com.foo.convert.DiscoveryService.execute(DiscoveryService.java:128)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

All the next calls to the task are successfull. My bet is that the persist service is not started yet, so I tried to inject an initializer :

```
public class MyInitializer { 
        @Inject MyInitializer(PersistService service) {
                service.start(); 
        } 
}
```

When injecting this initializer, Quartz jobs are working right away, but the `PersistFilter` calls `service.start()` a second time and my web application breaks :

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter Guice Filter
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Persistence service was already initialized.
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:142)
    at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.start(JpaPersistService.java:88)
    at com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter.init(PersistFilter.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.init(FilterDefinition.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172)
```

Injecting the `PersistFilter` in my `QuartzInitializer` does not help either.

The workaround I implemented so far is to wait one minute before starting the Quartz jobs but this is not a long-term solution.

Anybody had this problem before ?

Edit : This seems to be related to this issue [Issue 598: Persist Extension: PersistService.start() cannot be called multiple times](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=598)

Answer (score 4):

I found another workaround, by overriding the default persist filter implementation :

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import com.google.inject.persist.PersistService;
import com.google.inject.persist.UnitOfWork;

/**
 * Overrides Guice implementation to handle when the persistence service is
 * already started
 * 
 * See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402081/how-to-start-jpa-in-a-guice-
 * quartz-web-application
 */
@Singleton
public final class PersistFilter implements Filter {
    private final UnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private final PersistService persistService;

    @Inject
    public PersistFilter(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, PersistService persistService) {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.persistService = persistService;
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        try {
            persistService.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // Ignore exception is the persist service was already started
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        persistService.stop();
    }

    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse,
            final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        unitOfWork.begin();
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        } finally {
            unitOfWork.end();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, i can inject `MyInitializer` (which calls `persistService.start()`) in my `QuartzInitializer`, while using the `PersistFilter`.

Comment: Given thiat this is 90% verbatim copy of the code from the Guice class of the same name you should probably provide attribution, and it's subject to the restrictions from ASL 2.0 that you inherit when you modify an ASL 2.0 work... Also, you are re-implementing, not overriding since you do not inherit from their class.

Comment: @Gus PersistFilter is a final class... we cannot extend it.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with Ugo's `MyInitializer` workaround, when using it for JPA + Guice + Shiro, with a custom realm to get permissions from the db via jpa/hibernate. Whenever there was a mapping error the result was a million injection failures. The following reliably produced a single stack trace and quit immediately. It also seems a bit cleaner, explicitly starting the service rather than relying on an injection... I was worried that the order of injection might change and throw things off.

```
protected void configureServlets() {
    super.configureServlets();
    install(new JpaPersistModule("com.hcdware.jpa.persistence.unit"));

    final InjectionListener<PersistService> injectionListener = PersistService::start;

    TypeListener persistServiceListener = new TypeListener() {
        public <I> void hear(TypeLiteral<I> type, TypeEncounter<I> encounter) {
            if (PersistService.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
                TypeEncounter<PersistService> disposableEncounter = (TypeEncounter<PersistService>) encounter;
                disposableEncounter.register(injectionListener);
            }
        }
    };

    bindListener(new AbstractMatcher<TypeLiteral<?>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(TypeLiteral<?> typeLiteral) {
            return PersistService.class.isAssignableFrom(typeLiteral.getRawType());
        }
    }, persistServiceListener); 

    // proceed with the bindings...

}
```

From there, use the modified PersistFilter suggested by Ugo Méda

This was based on a nice article here: http://developer.vz.net/2012/02/08/extending-guice-2/

Answer (score 0):

Why and how do your quartz jobs end up using a persist filter? Quartz should use a separate threadpool unrelated to the http context where the PersistFilter runs. Overriding persistfilter to ignore exception is a code smell to me.  I just started unit of work in

```
execute(JobExecutionContext context) 

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    try {
        unitOfWork.begin();
        //use classes that  have em manager provider and decorated with        //@Transaction.
    } finally {
        unitOfWork.end();
    }
}
```